# How to retrieve number of fields,number of rows and name of fields form ADORecordSet_mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I want to retrieve number of fields,number of rows and name of fields from the ADORecordSet_mysql, so can anyone help me out.

Note: I am retrieving the query form database using Retrieve() function, and result I have stored in variable , so this variable returns a ADORecordSet_mysql, so I have to retrieve it all information from this AdoRecordSet_mysql